# Cycle time for 5hp well motor

Tags: water

What would be the time the 5hp well pump motor should run with a 530 gallon bladder pressure tank with a 40-60 on/off pressure switch. Air pressure in tank is at 35 psi. Currently runs for 3min 5 sec. Is this good or should it be shorter. Depending on demand, will cycle about between 12-25 min.

Comment: Manufacturer/model of pump?

Comment: That cycle time sounds good for that big of tank. We would really need to know how much water is used and the pump flow rate to fully answer your question.